# How to detect device rotation in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I would like to detect a live device rotation (not orientation, rotation in degrees) with Cordova. I used device motion but I get a bunch of acceleration x y and z values, how can I calculate rotation from this?

I would like to detect a full 360 degree rotation (imagine putting the device on a stick [or pendulum], and then hit it so it swings).

Thanks!

Comment: this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation gives you device rotation details in terms of degrees. Is it what your are looking for?

Comment: Hey @Ghandi, please have a look at the comment I left for Devrim.

Comment: got it now. Still not sure any thing other that device motion plugin is available... Will check though

Comment: device motion is the only plugin i could see which is close to this requirement. But device rotation count should be tracked using custom logic that needs to be built on top of the x,y,z co-ordinates. No ready made solution available in plugins yet as far as i checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [The Screen Orientation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/) by installing the [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) mentioned by Gandhi in the comment.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`

Then you can use an event to detect orientation change after `deviceReady`;

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(){
    console.log(screen.orientation.type); // e.g. portrait
});
```

or

```
screen.orientation.onchange = function({
    console.log(screen.orientation.type);
});
```

You should be able to do this without the plugin to be honest but would be would be safer to add the cordova plugin.

As you want to detect a 360 rotation, which isn't included, you need to count this yourself... Something along the lines of;

```
var startingPoint = 0;
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', monitorOrientation); 

function monitorOrientation(e) {
    console.log('Device orientation is: ', e. orientation);

    if(e. orientation == 180 || e.orientation == -180) {
        // You can extend this or remove it completely and increment the variable as you wish i.e. 4x90 = 360
        startingPoint += 180;
    }

    if(startingPoint == 360) {
        // Do whatever you want and reset starting point back to 0
        startingPoint = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Devrim, but the device doesn't rotate at all. It's standing. Imagine the device is glued to a stick in the landscape mode, and then you spin the stick. Orientation will not fire in this case, and that's the case I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that to be honest @trueicecold. I suppose then you are looking for device motion or sensor tools. Have a play with this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion

Comment: Yeah I saw it but I don't know how to normalize the x,y,z to detect a full 360 swing...

Answer (score 1):

maybe what you're looking for is the **compass** : 
[cordova-plugin-device-orientation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Device orientation plugin](http://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) gives you device rotation details in terms of degrees.

But if you are looking for detecting device motion, [device motion](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion) is the only plugin i could see which is close to this requirement. But device rotation count should be tracked using custom logic that needs to be built on top of the x,y,z co-ordinates. No ready made solution available in plugins yet as far as i checked

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the device's "live rotation" by using the acceleration x y and z values.

To use your pendulum analogy, assuming you know for sure the device will always be swinging left and right facing the user (ie traveling on the x-axis), you can use the X value.

Keep in mind you will not get degree values. Last time I checked, iOS return 0 for upright (portrait) then -9 to 9 when rotating from one landscape to the other.